How to convert Date from UTC to local time in Angular 16/17
I am getting the date from backend, and the date is stored in UTC format but I want it in local timings or IST
Didn't get anything relevant.  You find my code below, datetransform also didn't work
<div>{{item.capturedDate | date:"MMM dd, yyyy 'at'hh:mm a" }} </div>


In Angular, you can use the built-in DatePipe to convert UTC time to local time. You can also use the Date constructor and toLocaleString() method to achieve this. Below are two approaches you can use:
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

// Inside your component or service
export class YourComponentOrService {
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  convertUTCtoLocal(utcDate: string): string {
    const localDate = this.datePipe.transform(utcDate, 'medium', '+0530');
    return localDate;
  }
}

Using Date constructor:
export class YourComponentOrService {
  convertUTCtoLocal(utcDate: string): string {
    const date = new Date(utcDate);
    const localDate = date.toLocaleString('en-IN', {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'});
    return localDate;
  }
}


To convert a UTC date to local time in Angular, you can use the DatePipe provided by Angular.
Assuming item.capturedDate is a valid UTC date string (e.g., '2024-01-01 00:00:00')
<div>{{ item.capturedDate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy \'at\' hh:mm a' }}</div>

In this snippet:

We use the date pipe to format the item.capturedDate.
The format string 'MMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a' specifies how the date should be displayed. It includes the month abbreviation, day, year, hour, minute, and AM/PM indicator.
The date pipe automatically converts the UTC date to the local time zone of the user’s browser.

Remember to adjust the format string and ensure that item.capturedDate contains a valid UTC date string. The displayed time will be in the user’s local time zone (e.g., IST for users in India).

//.ts file
public displayDate = "2024-04-03T12:53:59+05:30";//UTC date and time
let dataDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.displayDate , 'MMM d, y, h:mm:ss a')
let yourDate: Date = new Date(dataDate + ' UTC');//converted date and time to lacal date and time
this.displayDate = yourDate;
//.html file
{{displayDate}}

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
